# Python turns strings into tuples after assigned to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a really weird python problem. I have already asked several colleagues who all had no idea how it happened and how it could be solved.

I have a shallow dict of strings that I receive from an API call and I want to assign some of those values to a new dict.

This is what the first dict looks like. Just a bunch of strings:
[image: This is what the first dict looks like. Just a bunch of strings]

I assign some values from dict1 to some keys in dict2. Really basic

```
    dict2={}
    dict2['access_key'] = dict1['access_key']
    dict2['secret_access_key'] = dict1['secret_access_key'],
    dict2['session_token'] =dict1['session_token'],
    dict2['region'] = dict1['region']
```

Then this happens. The values for "secret access key" and "session_token" are turned into tuples. "access_key" and "region" remain strings
[image: Then this happens. The values for "secret access key" and "session_token" are turned into tuples. "access_key" and "region" remain strings]

I have already tried initialising the values as strings, accessing the first entry of the tuple and casting the value to a string. All of that did not change anything. It seems like the value is assigned just fine and then something weird happens that turns it into a tuple

This is a screenshot of my Interpreter settings. I am using Pyython 3.6
[image: This is a screenshot of my Interpreter settings. I am using Pyython 3.6]

I am really going crazy over this one :-/ Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Remove the commas at the end of your lines. Commas make things into tuples.

Comment: Why do you have commas at the end of some lines where you copy over to dict2? Commas are used to define tuples in Python, could you check that part?

Comment: Probably a copy/paste error where you've left commas on the end of the line. I've been coding in Python for I don't know how long, perhaps 20 years, and still very occasionally make the mistake, and I end up in the debugger trying to work out what I've done.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have trailing commas at the end of two of your calls. This is why the strings are transformed to tuples.

Comment: You are absolutely right :-D Thank you very much. Damn those monday mornings

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer helped me too.  My hero!

Comment: Great catch!! Thanks :)

Comment: Amazing, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

My dear friend , the reason you have this problem is in Python tuple is idetified by commas.

You can try this code

```
a = 1, 
print(a,type(a))
b = 1
print(b,type(b))
```

So I update your code to this:

```
dict2={}
dict2['access_key'] = dict1['access_key']
# please notes the end !
# dict2['secret_access_key'] = dict1['secret_access_key'],
# dict2['session_token'] =dict1['session_token'],
# above is the origin code
dict2['secret_access_key'] = dict1['secret_access_key']
dict2['session_token'] =dict1['session_token']
dict2['region'] = dict1['region']
```

I think this will help!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following by removing the trailing commas:

```
dict2={}
dict2['access_key'] = dict1['access_key']
dict2['secret_access_key'] = dict1['secret_access_key']
dict2['session_token'] =dict1['session_token']
dict2['region'] = dict1['region']
```

Comment: That code looks exactly the same as the problem code.

Comment: please look at the trailing commas in the question. That is the issue.

Comment: Your answer should make that obvious.